# Creation of new matrix from A containing the average value of A rows for each column if B[i, j] == 1 where B is an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mean, adjacency-matrix

```
Suppose we have a matrix 

A =  1    2    3    4
     15   20   7   10 
     0    5   18   12


And an adjacency matrix 


B =   1     0     1    
      0     0     1    
      1     1     1
```

How can we get a new matrix containing the average value of A row for each column if B[i,j] == 1

```
Expected output matrix 
C =  0.5     3.5     10.5     8
     7.5    12.5     12.5     11
     5.33     9      9.33    8.66
```

To find the neighborhood if each i, I implemented the following code :

````
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        if (B[i,j] == 1):
            print(j)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the second column of your expected output matrix is correct?
I feel like this might be what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [15,20,7,10], [0,5,18,12]])
B = np.array([[1,0,1], [0,0,1], [1,1,1]])

np.divide(np.dot(A.T,B), B.sum(axis=1)).T
```

[image]

Comment: if you change B[1,1] to 1, then you would get exactly your expected result...

Comment: Thank you for your help, you're reason if we change B[1,1]=1 we got the second column of the expected output matrix. Another question please, why we don't get the same value of index_1 like  index_0 if we change  B[0,0] = 1 ?

Comment: sorry, I dont understand the question. B[0,0] is 1 in the given example... and what indices are you talking about? In case you mean having identical rows for B, you would end up with identical rows in C (try it out in the given code example)!